# Prove $\forall x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$: $x^2 \cos^2 (x) < 2$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Prove  $\forall x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$: $x^2 \cos^2 (x) < 2$

It is clear, that:

1. $x^2 \cos^2 (x) \to 0, x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$, since cosine goes to 0.
2. $x^2 \cos^2 (x) \to 0, x \to 0$, since $x$ goes to 0.

Of course, we can split $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ into $A_1 = (0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$, $ A_2 = [\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{3}]$ and $A_3 = [\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{2})$

(sorry for intersection, just don't want to write limits. It doesn't affect anything)

Then we take max and min values from $A_i$ and evaluate max value at $x^2$ and min value at $\cos^2 x$:

$A_1$: $\max(A_1)^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{16} \in (0, 1); \cos^2 \min(A_1) = 1 \implies \max(A_1)^2 \cos^2 \min(A_1) < 2$
$A_2$: $\max(A_2)^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{9} \in (1, 2) ; \cos^2 \min(A_2) = \frac{1}{2} \implies 
 \max(A_2)^2 \cos^2 \min(A_2) < 2$
$A_3$: $\max(A_3)^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{4} \in (2, 3) ; \cos^2 \min(A_3) = \frac{1}{4} \implies 
 \max(A_3)^2 \cos^2 \min(A_3) < 2$

Actually, here we can see that upper bound is even lower (not bigger that 1).

---

Unfortunately, I am not satisfied with this writing (somehow I am sure there are much better proofs).
But what are they? Thank you.

Comment: for $x \le 1$ it's obvious. Since $\cos x$ is decreasing, $x^2\cos^2 x \le \cos^2 1 \cdot x^2 <  0.25 \pi^2 \cos^2 1 <1$ for $x >1$

Comment: $x< \tan x$; $$x^2 \cos^2 x < \tan^2x\cos ^2x = \sin^2 x < 1 < 2.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall give you the Hint:

- Assume that $f(x)=x^2\cdot \cos^2x$, and then prove, $$f'(x)=2x\cos x(\cos x-x\sin x)$$
- Find the maxima of $f(x)$ between $\left[0,{\pi\over2}\right]$. As $f(0)=f({\pi\over2})=0$ so there must be peak between $\left[0,{\pi\over2}\right]$. Hence, $f'(x)=0$ has the maxima. And for your inequality to be true maxima$<2$

Comment: Finding the zeros of $f'$ isn't so straightforward.   It's equvalent to solving $\cot(x)=x$.

Comment: @Randall why is there any need to find zeros? Just we need to substitute the value of $\cos x$ in terms of $x$ and then just compare for the given domain.

Comment: Your argument was based on "peaks" which implies you should find maxima.  There is a critical point at roughtly $x \approx 0.86$ which is well within the domain.  If your argument doesn't use this approach, you should update your answer to be clearer.

Comment: @Randall I never said there is need to find maxima. I said maxima will be attained at $f'(x)=0$. And the maxima can be calculated in terms of $x$. Where $x$ is the point which has maxima. And the maxima will be ${x^2}\over{1+x^2}$. And clearly this is $<1$. (Avoid extra calculation when there is no need)

Comment: +1 great approach.

Comment: Where $x$ is the point which has maxima $f(x)$, $\cot x = x$, $\cos^2 x$ alone is $= \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$, and the whole $f(x) = x^2\cos^2 x = \frac{x^4}{1+x^2} = x^2 - 1 + \frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: @peterwhy yes, I forgot to multiply. But it still satisfy. As $x<1.57$

Answer (score 2):

This is based on the inequality $x< \tan x$ for $x\in\left(0, \frac \pi2\right)$.

(Geometrically, this can be obtained by comparing the areas of 1) a sector with unit radius and angle $x$, and 2) a right-angled triangle with adjacent side $1$ and opposite side $\tan x$.)

$$\begin{align*}
x &< \tan x\\
x^2 \cos^2 x &< \tan^2x\cos ^2x\\
&= \sin^2 x < 1 < 2
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Although your method is nice. But for a strong inequality it won't work. For example $x^2\cos^2x<0.5$ is true for the given domain.